# How can I bubble an "impossible" value up via a recursive algorithm?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

I have a recursive algorithm with special cases, for example a path algorithm where I want to add 1 to the distance if the path is good, but return -1 if it hits a dead-end.  This is problematic when solving maximization problems with a bunch of recursive calls.

Is there a better way to code the following:

```
def rec(n):
  if n == 1:
    return -1
  if n == 0:
    return 1
  val = rec(n - 2)
  if val == -1:
    return -1
  else:
    return val + 1
```

Therefore, `rec(4) = 2`, `rec(3) = -1`

Comment: Since you know that an odd starting number will result in -1, why not first check for `n % 2 == 1` and return -1 if true. That will terminate the recursion on the first call to `rec()`

Comment: Conceptually, one may be able to use exceptions for such a purpose.  In both Java and .NET, throwing an exception is sufficiently expensive that such usage would be inefficient because their exception mechanisms are designed to avoid overhead in the no-exception case, but some other languages may accept some slight overhead in the no-exception case for purposes of speeding up exception processing.

Comment: Alternatively, it may be possible to use a very large number rather than -1 to indicate the "no path available" scenario.  The number should be small enough that one can do math on it without overflow, but larger than any legitimate solution.  For example, if the base-line "no solution" case which returned 1,000,000,000 was called many levels deep, each calling level could probably add one to the returned value without risking integer overflow.

Comment: @jonhopkins: This is just an contrived example to illustrate the idea. ;)

Comment: @supercat: Both ideas are interesting. Can you submit them as answers? Hopefully there will be other creative ideas as well.

Comment: Ah, okay. Other than my previous comment, your current code is how I've always bubbled values up, too... I like @supercat's second proposal though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, not really. You could make it clearer in Python by returning `None` rather than -1; this has the advantage that erroneously adding to the invalid value will throw an exception.

A language that has a more rigorous type system and a good concept of 'maybe' or optional values makes it a snap. Say, Haskell:

```
rec 1 = Nothing
rec 0 = Just 1
rec n = map ((+) 1) $ rec (n - 2)
```

The `map` invocation means that it will add whatever is in the box if it is `Just x`, and return the invalid value (`Nothing`) unchanged. Of course, you can design your own more sophisticated type that allows for multiple error conditions or whatever and still obtain similarly simple results. This is pretty much just as easy in OCaml, F#, Standard ML, and Scala.

You can simulate this approach with `None` in Python by defining a helper function:

```
def mapMaybe(obj, f):
    if obj is None:
        return None
    else:
        return f(obj)
```

Then you can do:

```
return mapMaybe(val, lambda x: x + 1)
```

But I don't know that I would really recommend doing that.

Simulating a trick from Scala's book, it would also be possible to wrap all of this up in generator comprehensions (untested):

```
def maybe(x):
    if x is not None:
        yield x

def firstMaybe(it):
    try:
        return it.next()
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

Then:

```
return firstMaybe(x + 1 for x in maybe(val))
```

But that's really non-standard, non-idiomatic Python.

Answer (score 1):

A useful technique is to select a "no solution available" value such that processing it as though it represented a solution would still yield a "no solution available" value.  If low numbers represent optimal solutions, for example, one could choose a value which is larger than any valid solution which would be of interest.  If one is using integer types, one would have to make sure the "no solution available" value was small enough that operating on it as though it were a valid solution would not cause numerical overflows [e.g. if recursive calls always assume that the cost of a solution from some position will be one greater than the cost of a solution generated by the recursive call, then using values greater than 999,999,999 to represent "no solution avaialble" should work; if code might regard the cost of the solution as being the sum of two other solutions, however, it may be necessary to choose a smaller value].  Alternatively, one might benefit from using floating-point types since a value of "positive infinity" will compare greater than any other value, and adding any positive or finite amount to it won't change that.